# Keyboard stops functioning and after a while blue screen of death occurs - How can I diagnose why?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bsod, lenovo-laptop

My computer recently (today) started to do this behaviour. I experienced it twice within the previous 3 hours. The symptoms are the following:

1. normally using the computer
2. keyboard all of a sudden stops functioning (the backlight, num lock, caps lock state states are still as they were, switching them is impossible)
3. Windows with mouse control still functioning properly
4. after 3-4 minutes blue screen of death occurs, it restarts the computer
5. BIOS-like dialog shows up to choose from: Normal startup, BIOS setup, Boot menu, System Recovery. Up and down arrows and everything else still not functioning (!).
6. I have to turn off the computer by long pressing the power button.

My configuration:

- Lenovo Y700
- Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU
- 16 GB Ram
- Windows 10 Pro
- Current Windows installation is approximately 3-4 years old, but otherwise functioning properly

How can I diagnose what causes the problem? Please help me, this is so frustrating.

(note: I don't have any restore points, I've just checked)

Comment: You will find in the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump` one or more `.dmp` files. Please zip these files one-by-one (using 7Zip gives better compression) and post somewhere we can download (OneDrive, dropbox etc) to analyze the crashes.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc). In there, look in the Windows > Application and Windows System logs. Also, sometimes the BSOD page can have some helpful messages. A picture of what it shows might be helpful.

Comment: @harrymc thank you in advance, here they are: https://filebin.net/7tb5fbarfkfv72z5

Comment: @Meow_ly I found nothing useful in the EventLog. I'm on reproducing the BSOD, if I did I'll post the picture, but as far as I remember there was nothing useful there either only an error code I think DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE.

Comment: This is a very general error code. It occurs in the kernel and no driver is clearly indicated. Check your drivers and BIOS at [Lenovo](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-y-series-laptops/y700-15isk/downloads/driver-list). For hardware, the power supply is more likely. But these are only guesses.

Comment: Thank you guys. I should delete this question as the problem hasn't occurred since?

Comment: No, if you know how you fixed this you should self-answer your question. If not then... just let it be.